# In JIRA, is the burndown chart ignored when associating a new workflow and new statuses in your project?

Tags: project-management, jira, sprint, backlog, burndowncharts

I've introduced a new workflow that I'm using for my project, and everything looks so good so far. There was one unintended effect,though.

When I applied everything and the new statuses were applied to current issues, the burndown chart showed everything as if they had been removed from "Resolved". It trended back upward, as if the things that were done become not done.

Now, if I act on the issues and use one of the transitions, it burns down properly (the statuses have been mapped to the "Complete" state in the transitions).  This makes me wonder: does the association that happens in a new workflow disregard the burndown chart?  Which properties should I address to ensure that everything previously marked as Complete remains so and is reflected in the burndown chart?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell: yes, it is ignored. I tried applying the workflow to another project and wound up with the same result. All previously resolved issues were marked as unresolved, even though the transitions even have a change to the Resolution field that makes them Done.